# Preserve Scroll Position in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I want to preserve scroll position after viewing an individual post. I can do this when I went to individual post, and then not scrolling in individual post, return back to home page. It will preserver the scroll position. But when I scrolled in the individual post page, and then return to home page, the scroll position is messed up. Here are snippets of the code:

Home.jsx

```
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
    const [startIndex, setStartIndex] = useState(0);
    const [range, setRange] = useState(6);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)


    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchPosts = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axios.get(`/api/posts`);
                setPosts(response.data);
                console.log(response.data);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            } finally {
                setLoading(false);
            }
        };

        fetchPosts();
        setRange(sessionStorage.getItem('range') ? parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem('range')) : 6);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        const attemptScrollRestore = () => {
            const savedPosition = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem('HomeScroll') || '0');
            if (document.body.scrollHeight > savedPosition) {
                window.scrollTo(0, savedPosition);
            } else {
                setTimeout(attemptScrollRestore, 50); 
            }
        };

        if (loading === false) { 
            attemptScrollRestore();
        }
    }, [loading]); // This useEffect depends on the loading state


    useEffect(() => {
        const handleScroll = () => {
          sessionStorage.setItem('HomeScroll', window.scrollY.toString());
        }

        window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
        };
    }, []);
```

Post.jsx

```
    const [post, setPost] = useState({});
    const [comment, setComment] = useState('');
    const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);
    const [honeypot, setHoneypot] = useState("");
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
    const {postID} = useParams();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }, []);


    useEffect(() => {



        const fetchPosts = async () => {
            const response = await axios.get("/api/singlePost", {
                params: {
                    id: postID
                }
            });
            setPost(response.data);
        }

        const fetchComments = async () => {
            const response = await axios.get("/api/getComments", {
                params: {
                    id: postID
                }
            });
            setComments(response.data);
        }

        const updatePosts = async () => {
            const response = await axios.put(`/api/updatePost?id=${postID}`);
        }
        fetchPosts();
        fetchComments();

        const timer = setTimeout(() => {
            updatePosts();
        }, 1750);

        return () => clearTimeout(timer);

    }, [postID]);
```

I did try to not change scroll position in Post.jsx, but it still not working. Tried to use custom state also not working. It seems like something in Post.jsx messing up with the local storage? Or when I went back to homepage, it resetted to 0,0 without giving a chance to restore the scroll position. That what I can think of right now. Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether or not you are using `react-router-dom` but what I'd do in your case is to create an AppLayout where I will store the position then with the `useOutletContext()`, I will pass the current position to where it is needed. I reckon you can use the default `useContext()` for that as well.

I believe the `sessionStorage` should be used to save more valuable data, in my opinion.

**From your codebase:**

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}, []);
```

This to make your page scroll back to the top on DOM load.

Then I suggest you take this snippet to the AppLayout I suggested so it can track the user's scroll active and perhaps store the data on a state prop.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      sessionStorage.setItem('HomeScroll', window.scrollY.toString());
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
}, []);
```

**To this:**

```
const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
 setScrollPosition(window.scrollY);
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => {
       window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
}, []);
```

You can now add the scrollPosition into a Outlet context.

Then back to your **Home.jsx**

```
const [scrollPosition] = useOutletContext();
useEffect(() => {
    const attemptScrollRestore = () => {
        if (document.body.scrollHeight > scrollPosition) {
            window.scrollTo(0, scrollPosition);
        } 
    };

    if (loading === false) { 
        attemptScrollRestore();
    }
}, [loading]); // This useEffect depends on the loading state
```

I didn't see the need for the else block, to be honest.

Hopefully this helps.